# bashrc function to ssh into a server based on arguments

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to ssh into many servers with relative ease. The servers follow a similar naming scheme, like `blah1@blah.com`, `blah2@blah.com`, etc. I currently have bash aliases that have a 1:1 mapping. So if I want to connect to `blah1@blah.com` I type `blah1`. But I was wondering if I can do that all in 1 function.
I tried generalizing it by:

```
blah() {
    ssh blah$*@blah.com
}
```

and invoking it using `blah 1`
But that didn't work. How can I do what I want?

Comment: Your script works for me.  It's not entirely correct and robust, but it does what you expect with a single numeric argument.

Answer (score 2):

`$1` is argument number 1.

```
 blah() {
    ssh blah$1@blah.com
 }
```